Operator globally hypoelliptic
An operateor $T$ is globally hypoelliptic if :
$u\in S'(\Bbb R^n),Tu\in S(\Bbb R^n)$ imply $u\in S(\Bbb R^n)$.
My question why if $u\in L^2(\Bbb R^n): Tu =\lambda u$. Then $u\in S(\Bbb R^n)$.
where $\lambda\in\Bbb R^n$, $S(\Bbb R^n)$ is the Schwartz space and
$S'(\Bbb R^n)$ is the space of all tempered distributions

Umm, for $T = Id$, that is $Tu \equiv u$ it is clearly globally hypoelliptic, but your condition is not satisfied...

when T=Id, If $u\in S'(R^n)$ and $Tu=u\in S(R^n)$. Then $u\in S(R^n)$

Yes, and yet there exists $u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for which $Tu = u$ but which is not Schwartz, e.g. literally any $L^2$-function.
